# How write a word for "× "?

Tags: word-usage

In the sentence:

> If they do not copy the object accurately,the teacher may mark × through their paper and have them try again.

How write a word for "×" ?

Comment: In British English it's called a cross (Oxford says **a cross (×) used to show that something is incorrect or unsatisfactory**), though I notice that American dictionaries don't include the 'incorrect' meaning for the cross mark, so maybe they call it something else.

Comment: In my schooldays (UK) teachers used a cross **×** for a wrong answer, and a tick **✓** for a correct one.

Comment: When you say "the teacher may mark × through their paper", do you literally mean make the mark right across the object, or just put × somewhere on the paper?

Answer (score 1):

In US English, we would usually just call it [**an X**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/x).  For example,

> [The X mark symbol  (also known as a cross, cross-mark, x sign, ex symbol) is often used in documents as a sign of refusal, reject, to indicate the concept "no" or "wrong"; or as an indicator of a completed task, a finished step, etc.](https://www.officetooltips.com/word_365/tips/how_to_insert_check_mark_and_x_mark_in_word.html)

Saying "mark an X *through their paper*" sounds weird, though, because "through the paper" sounds like "piercing the paper".  We would say **mark the paper with an X** or **mark the answer with an X**.

For example,

> [One or both parties would sign their name or mark the paper with an 'X'](https://books.google.com/books?id=MFzdCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT31&dq=%22mark%20the%20paper%20with%20an%20x%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjlzPaw8MX4AhXlTN8KHXIwAK0Q6AF6BAgEEAI)

> [Mark with an "X" this amount on the medicine dropper](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Workbook_for_Mosby_s_Textbook_for_Medica/8ydgEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=mark%20%22with%20an%20x%22&pg=PA39&printsec=frontcover)

> [If incorrect , please mark " X " in the appropriate box](https://books.google.com/books?id=BvGSJ15tymsC&pg=PP1&dq=incorrect%20%22mark%20x%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinorCK8MX4AhXmlYkEHZbGDXkQ6AF6BAgHEAI)

Comment: Thanks for giving the American angle.